# Cookies in Iframe page loaded with Curl

Tags: php, cookies, curl

On http://aegon.nl you'll get an opt-in which only displays when you haven't got the right cookie set for the website.

Now I'm trying to load the website in an Iframe with an injected file (to do some fancy stuff with javaScript). To be able to do that, I need to CURL the sourcecode and change the base href to "aegon.nl" in order to show the same layout (for the url's to the stylesheets and such).

Now, been there and done that. But now I've got a problem with the cookies. I can click the button in the opt-in as many times as I want, but It keeps coming back. I only have this problem after CURLing the content and changing the base href.

After searching the sourcecode I think I found the problem:

```
var dom=(window.location.hostname.indexOf(".")>0)?'aegon.nl':window.location.hostname;
var AEGONCookieSettings = new AEGON.CookieOptIn(dom)
```

Probably the problem is solved by changing this part of sourcecode.... But that doesn't solve the problem for the other websites which are using the same kind of opt-in.

Does anyone have a solution for this?